# How can I have two classes share the same variable definitions

Tags: java, xml, swing, oop

What I really need is to be able to declare regular variables in an interface and implement that interface in two classes that I would not have to have to re-declare these in each class (ie class.data.variables instead of class.variables).  Is there any way that I could achieve the same goal differently?

To give more detail.  Essentially, I have created a small drawing program that drops JLabels on a JPanel that is on a JScrollPane.  Because I have a specific design for these JLabels (ie they are not just for drawing they represent airline objects for this application), I have a class that extends JLabel and adds my application specific variables to it.  Ultimately, I read and write an XML file with these variables so they can load and save their designs.  Since I can not use this extended class for my XML definitions because it screams about the parent class even though I told it to have NONE as the accessor (I read there is a bug), I have to create an identical class and copy values back and forth for saving and loading.  Not too much of a problem except when I add a variable to the JLabel extended class and forget to add it to the XML mimic class and subsequent copy routines.

So, it would be great if I could make one class (say CellDataRecord.java) that held the extra data declarations and have that class be used in both places (the JLabel extension and the XML data) without having to have something like XML.data.CellDataRecordXXX.

Comment: What you are describing would be called a *mix-in* -- and Java doesn't have those. You'll have to resort to one pattern or the other, which you are already familiar with.

Comment: same problem as mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with inheritance or using an interface, where the variable is set as a constant in the parent class. Since you are extending a JLabel, you should implement the interface on both classes:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    int someint = 9;
}

public class MyClass1 extends JLabel implements MyInterface {
    //this class has access to `someint`
}

public class MyClass2 extends JLabel implements MyInterface {
    // also has access to `someint`
}
```

## Edit

Since you want to be able to change the same variable from different classes, you have to ensure you aren't changing copies and are changing the same variable, so you should use a `volatile` keyword on the variable to indicate to java that all threads should check the value before it updates it.

Now you'll need to have a separate class so that instances can be made from other classes to get the value. You have to use the `static` keyword to ensure that one copy is kept for all class instances.

```
public class MyVariableWrapper {
    public static volatile int some_var = 9;
    public void updateSomeVar(int newvar) {
         some_var = newvar;
    }
    public int getSomeVar() { return some_var; }
}
```

Now the other two classes just do this:

```
public class MyClass1 extends JLabel {
    MyVariableWrapper myVariableWrapper;
    MyClass1() {
        super();
        myVariableWrapper = new MyVariableWrapper();
        // now I have access to `some_var`
    }
}

public class MyClass2 extends JLabel {
    MyVariableWrapper myVariableWrapper;
    MyClass2() {
        super();
        myVariableWrapper = new MyVariableWrapper();
        // now I have access to the same `some_var` as MyClass1
    }

    // this is a wrapper method for your convenience
    // since you don't like the excess code when accessing the variable
    public int getSomeVar() {
        return myVariableWrapper.some_var;
        // or myVariableWrapper.getSomeVar();
    }
    public void setSomeVar(int newvar) {
        myVariableWrapper.some_var = newvar;
        // or myVariableWrapper.setSomeVar(newvar);
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2();
System.out.println(""+myClass2.getSomeVar());
```

Comment: My understanding is that if I use an interface then all my "variables" become "constants" and I need them to be variables.  So, if I understand correctly, an interface will not work for me.

Comment: @JesterHawk Oh right, you just need to declare the variable in its own class as `static` and `volatile`, and then create instances of that class from the two classes which need the variable. Here is an example of using a volatile variable in java: http://ilkinbalkanay.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/volatile-variables-in-java.html

Comment: Ok, then to use some_var, I would have to do something like myVariableWrapper.some_var, right?

Comment: @JesterHawk since its static, yes. But you could also use a getter/setter like I made in the example above

Comment: That was what I was hoping to avoid.  I know I can instantiate the original class in other classes.  But then when I reference, I would have to do things like subclass1.data.originalclassvariable.  I was hoping to do this without the ".data." part as I have too much already written code to have to go back and change it all.  That is why I was wondering if there was a way to basically have an interface that would have actually variables.

Comment: @JesterHawk I didn't understand that? If you don't like using the static call on variables, use a getter and setter like the example I gave you. This is a variable? Interfaces only allow constants. If you don't want to use `myVariableBlah.updateVariable()` you just have to wrap it in another setter, I will update my answer to explain further.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying.  The down side is that I have thousands of lines of code that access one of the two classes that I wanted to use my base class and if I do something like that, while it would work and probably should have done that from the start), I would now have to change a lot of code.  Instead at the moment, I just have to make sure I copy all the data to the XML writer/reader class I have.

Comment: @JesterHawk you don't have to break old code to add new features, that's what inheritance is for. Just extend your old classes and add new methods like in my example to have access to the volatile variables.

Comment: Ahhhhh, now I see what you are saying.  Sometimes it takes a few tries, but I eventually get there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I 100% grasp your problem but from the first few lines of your description, instead of implementing an interface, you could define an abstract class and have your classes extend it. That way, you'll be able to define attributes in the abstract class and these will be common to all subclasses.

Comment: Yes, the catch is that the one extends JLabel because I need the ability of it to be drawn on a JPanel.  And since I can not have a class extend both JLabel and an Abstract class (which would actually be cool and helpful), that does not work.

Comment: I did try having the JLabel as a component of the class but ran into issues with the drawing portion.  Probably my lack of knowledge.  But essentially I had issues with removing.  For example, the user mouses over and clicks to delete a "cell" that contains the JLabel.  I could get it to remove from pane but finding which "cell" it was in the ArrayList proved unstable.  I was checking the component but it didn't always find it.  So, I was left without a reliable way to remove the "cell" both from the JPanel and the ArrayList.  Again, probably my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @JesterHawk but you can implement as many interfaces as you wish

Comment: @Ozzy, yes, but if I understand correct interfaces only give me constans, right?  If so, then that will not work because I need variables.